# Jasper server Active Directory conf erroe :Invalid content was found starting with element 'value'

Tags: active-directory, jasperserver, spring-ldap, spring-security-ldap

I'm authenticationg jasperserver 5.6.1 to microsoft active directy reference to this.
[https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/jasperreports-authentication-cookbook/v56/authentication-microsoft-active-directory]

but when I compile and run the server there's a log error.

cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'value'. One of '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":meta, ' is expected.

The erroe occered userSearch bean in span class="Forceful".

```
<bean id="userSearch"
      class="org.springframework.security.ldap.search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch">
  <constructor-arg index="0"><value><span class="Forceful">cn=Users</span></value></constructor-arg>
  <constructor-arg index="1"><value><span class="Forceful">(sAMAccountName={0})</span></value></constructor-arg>
  <constructor-arg index="2"><ref local="ldapContextSource"/></constructor-arg>
  <property name="searchSubtree"><value>true</value></property>
</bean>
```

How to fix this error ?

Best Regards,
Chinthaka

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the  class from both constructor-arg's.

They should look like this..

```
<constructor-arg index="0"><value>cn=Users</value></constructor-arg>
<constructor-arg index="1"><value>(sAMAccountName={0})</value></constructor-arg>
```

Hope that helps..

Comment: I tried that one.But it couldn't work on new jasper server version 5.6.1.